# Remove html tags from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the a column in my table which stores a paragraph like below :

```
<p>I like it.</p>this is my job.<main>current.</main>
```

I want to remove the tags `<p>`, `</p>,`  and  and all tags between `<` and `>`.
So my expected output will be like below :

```
I like it. this is my job. current.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please try this

```
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<p>I like it.</p>this is my job.<main>current.</main>'

SELECT x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') FROM ( SELECT x = 
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@txt, '>', '/>'), '</', '<') AS XML) ) r
```

this will help to remove all tags

Comment: @samir, you can try to add this in order to fiddle in blanks in between: `SELECT STUFF(x.query('for $nd in /root/text() return concat(" ",$nd)').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
FROM ( SELECT x = 
CAST('<root>' +REPLACE(REPLACE(@txt, '>', '/>'), '</', '<') + '</root>' AS XML) ) r`

Comment: @xXx you must find the used entities (always an ampersand, some code and a semicolon, e.g. `&quot;`) and either replace them oder define them for XML (which is tricky...)

Comment: @samir, one more suggestion: Replace any `/>` with `/> ` (additional blank) to get blanks in between

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE: Samir's answer is better than mine as it can deal with html-crap

(as long as there is no `<` or `>` as normal content :-)

### You can try this:

If your string is valid XML (meaning `XHTML`) you might go this route:

```
DECLARE @yourString NVARCHAR(100)=N'<p>I like it.</p>this is my job.<main>current.</main>';

SELECT CAST(@yourString AS XML).value('.','nvarchar(max)');
```

returns

```
I like it.this is my job.current.
```

Using `.` as the XPath will return the whole content *as is*...

Any invalid XML (very likely with simple html) will break this...

Comment: When I try to apply Samir's solution like below : SELECT x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') FROM ( SELECT x = 
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(ActivityDescription as nvarchar(max)), '>', '/>'), '</', '<') AS XML) FROM Competitor ) r I get the following error :  XML parsing: line 1, character 43, well formed check: undeclared entity

Answer (score 2):

You can use giant `REPLACE()` :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '<p>', ''), '</p>', ''), '<main>, ''), '</main>', '')
```

If you are working the latest SQL version then this will be easy to write using `TRANSLATE()` :

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(col, '<p></p><main></main>', '')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) remove all "p", "m", "a", "i", "n" characters? And give an error due to different lengths of 2nd and 3rd params

Answer (score 1):

If u want remove tags when select, you can do a normal SELECT and clear string:

```html
SELECT column FROM my_table;
$value = $row["column"];
$value_replaced = str_replace('<p>', '', $value);
$value = $value_replaced;
$value_replaced = str_replace('</p>', '', $value);
$value = $value_replaced;
$value_replaced = str_replace('<main>', '', $value);
$value = $value_replaced;
$value_replaced = str_replace('</main>', '', $value);
```